# Storing Seekbar value but keep getting that I have to use final

Tags: android, development-environment, final, calculated-field

"Variable is accessed within inner class Needs to be declared final" is the the error I get at first. So I change it to final. Once I change it to final I get a different error saying "Cannot assign value to final variable". I'm kind of stuck here on what to do here. Its giving me the error on int exam_grade

```
    public class CalculateGradeActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculate_grade_view);
    seekbar();



}
public void seekbar(){
    SeekBar seek_bar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarExam);


    final TextView text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentageSeekbar1);



    int exam_grade;
    TextView text_view5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numeric_grade_id_output);
    text_view5.setText(String.valueOf(exam_grade));


    int progress = seek_bar1.getProgress();
    text_view.setText(String.valueOf(progress));




    seek_bar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(

            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    exam_grade = progress;
                    text_view.setText(String.valueOf(progress) + "%");


                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            }
    );








}//ends seekbar function
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi don't declare your textview as final, put it in the class attributes instead.

```
public class CalculateGradeActivity extends Activity {

    TextView text_view;
    SeekBar seek_bar1


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculate_grade_view);
    seek_bar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarExam);
    text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentageSeekbar1);
    seekbar();

}
```

Do the same for all views(Declare them as attributes).

Comment: Thanks!! Had to place my exam_grade variable in the class attributes also

Answer (score 0):

final means it can only be assigned once.
I feel sure that textview shouldn't be final.
anyway,
try putting the declarations of exam grade and TextView in your onCreate...

```
     setContentView(R.layout.calculate_grade_view);
     int exam_grade;
     TextView text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentageSeekbar1);
     seekbar();
```